# jQuery UI Resizable - Multiple DIVs Resizing Pushing Other DIVs Around

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, html

I've been playing around with a page that has a div containing multiple other divs and jQuery UI resizable.  It's basically a dashboard with individual widgets.  What I need is to be able to resize each individual "widget" div independent of every other div inside the containing div.

Currently, if I resize a div it pushes the other divs out of the way.  I need to resize a div and have it not affect the other divs (even if the div being resized goes behind or over the top of any other divs).  After trying a number of different things, I'm having trouble getting it implemented.

I've created a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/gattml/Th75t/) that shows a mock up of what I have to date.

Here's some snippets:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">

    <div class="widgetList">
        <div class="widgetRefresh">
            <div class="widgetResizable">
                <div class="widget-header">
                    <span>header1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-body">
                    <span>body1</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...other "widget" divs here...

    </div>
</div>

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.widgetList {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-width: 80px;
    outline: 1px solid green;
}

.widgetResizable {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 1px dashed red;
}

.widget-header {
    outline: 1px dashed blue;
}

.widget-body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 4px;
    outline: 1px dashed green;
}

var $widget = $(".widgetList");
var $widgetResizable = $widget.find(".widgetResizable");
$widgetResizable.css("height", "170px");
$widget.draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    grid: [4, 4],
    handle: ".widget-header",
    opacity: 0.85,
    zIndex: 100
});
$widgetResizable.resizable({
    grid: [4, 4],
    handles: "e, s, se",
    minHeight: 100,
    minWidth: 80
});
```

So, how can I implement my resizable "widget" divs so that they do not push around the other "widget" divs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your box in motion will need to be absolute. You can either add a class, which I recommend, on the start:function(){}  or add css properties. You will also need to add a z-index value to make your box sit ontop of the other boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/Th75t/7/

```
start:function(event,ui){
        ui.element.css('position','absolute');
    }
```

BETTER

```
start:function(event,ui){
        ui.element.addClass('active');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried your suggestion and it almost works.  I had to change the start event to: ui.element.parents('.widgetList').css('position', 'absolute').css('z-index', 1000); because the .widgetList container class was kinda getting screwed up and I was losing the container and border.  But, the main reason I say your solution 'almost works' is that when I resize a widget div, all other divs shift so that there is always one at position 0, 0 (until I resize and move them all).  I guess I need to absolutely position all widget divs from the start (or something).

Comment: You could clone() the moving DIV, append it right .after() the current animated DIV and set the cloned DIV to visibility:hidden;